# add error from trigger when enabling partner user from contact

Tags: validation, contact, user, partner

Is there is a way to stop / add error from contact trigger when a user try to create a partner user from contact ?

I would like to add error in case certain field say firstname is missing on contact, then block enabling that contact convert to a partner user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contact trigger will not fire when you enable contact as portal user. I have checked it by creating a trigger on contact and enabled contact as a portal user. The last modified date remains the same.

[image]
[image]
[image]

You can write validation rule on the User object or trigger on the User object.

Comment: Thank you @Sanket for the details here :)